# Get Sales data from Amazon MWS API

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon MWS API to get Sales information. How do I get the SKU, Purchase date, Quantity sold information. Do I have to make separate call to different API. Though I am able to connect to Order API to get Order Id.

Answer (score 2):

Once you know the Order ID, call the `ListOrderItems` operation of the Orders API and that will give you what you're looking for.  Documentation is right here: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrderItems.html

In addition, there is a Reports API that has a number of Order reports.  With this API, you call `RequestReport` with the report type you want, and then call `GetReport` using the GeneratedReportId that you are given after making the request. http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports

Comment: Strongly suggest using reports API if you are planning on retrieving any volume of data.  Orders API has very tight restrictions.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Depending on what the intent of the application is, there are a couple ways to get order data.  I have use cases where I do both.

Comment: I originally designed an Orders Sync program around the Orders API.. ran for a day and I had to completely redesign around the Reports API.  Figured I would mention it to help someone else avoid the hassle ;p

Comment: @ScottG - thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at the report api and see how quickly it fetches data  as with orders api I have to first get the order id and then make another request to get the details and since I have 100's of order in a couple of days and fetching every details seems to be not feasible

Comment: I think _GET_ORDERS_DATA_ report will give me SKU, purchase date and quantity Sold. But can I get data in real time? Any idea?

Comment: I think they should be fairly close to real time, but I'm not entirely sure as I don't use that report.  I download an FBA inventory report every 30 minutes and instantly process that into my system and it has worked out great for a couple years now.

Comment: @ScottG - if I too use FBA inventory report can I get SKU, Quantity Sold, Purchase date from this api? Also why do you run it in every 30 minutes - is your data keeps on changing - also are you processing the data and saving it in database. Actually my requirement was to create a report which on refresh goes to mws api and fetch the above data. I thought that fetching might take time so lets save the data in database so we can have apply the filtering also if that is needed. Right now I am not sure how frequently should I call the api i.e. my intermediary code to fetch required data.

Comment: @ScottG, I got confused but I don't want a inventory report as I am interested in Sales data

Comment: What I would do is download the report you need every xx minutes to a folder.  Then any time you need to refresh your own report, read in the latest version of the report you downloaded, configure the data the way you want it, and show the report.  No need to store in a database, unless maybe you have other data there you want to show.  Up to your requirements.

Comment: Sure, my original answer above points to the Reports API.  Read the documentation there and look at the C# SDK.

Comment: @ScottG Hi,  I've to fetch day wise gross sales for list of sellers. Please suggest my which APIs I used to implement this. Thnx in advance